# How to stack two subfigures next to a third subfigure?

Tags: positioning, subfloats

I'm using the subfigure environment to show 3 graphics in one figure environment. However, I'd like to arrange them in the following order (subfig1 is larger than the other two):

```
| SUBFIG1 | SUBFIG2 |
| SUBFIG1 | SUBFIG3 |
```

How can this be achieved? I've tried to add a linebreak, but that moved the third subfigure below the other two.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use two subfigure environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{x}
\caption{A tall figure}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
\caption{A short figure}

\vspace{2ex}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{x}
\caption{A short figure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{The full caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]