# How to stack two subtables next to a third subtable?

Tags: positioning, subfloats, minipage

Same as described in this question [How to stack two subfigures next to a third subfigure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83069/how-to-stack-two-subfigures-next-to-a-third-subfigure), this time is the opposite and with tables. Instead of this

```
| SUBTBL1 | SUBTBL3 |    
| SUBTBL2 | SUBTBL3 |
```

i got this:

```
| SUBTBL1 |  BLANK  |    
| SUBTBL2 | SUBTBL3 |
```

i tried with position of minipage t instead of b same as c but it didnt work

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
text & text & text & text \\ \hline
\hline
text & text & text & text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL1}
\end{table}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL2}
\end{table}
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL3}
\end{table}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have the wrong order of environments. You need only one `table` environment, and inside that you have multiple `minipage` environments.

Comment: But how to put a caption to every single subtable ? or i have to only put a global caption ?

Comment: See my answer, you can have multiple captions in the same `table` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having `table` environments inside `minipage`s, use one `table` environment and two `minipage`s inside that. You can have multiple captions inside the same `table` (or `figure`) environment.

Note that with two minipages of `0.5\linewidth` next to each other and a `\quad` space between, you'll get an overfull box and the second minipage poking a little bit into the right margin. Depending on situation, remove the space between the minipages altogether, with

```
\end{minipage}% <-- percentcharacter removes space from line feed
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
```

or reduce the  width a little bit, and use `\hfill` instead of `\quad` (as in the example below).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
text & text & text & text \\ \hline
\hline
text & text & text & text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL1}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL2}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL3}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you want the right table bottom aligned with the lower left one you can, assuming the captions have the same height, add the `[b]` positional argument to both `minipage` environments, so you have

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
```

for both of them. (If the captions have different heights, and you want the first line of the caption vertically aligned to each other, some other action must be taken, I don't know off-hand the best of achieving that,  but it can probably be done with the `floatrow` package, and there might well be a question about this somewhere on the site.)

Comment: @Mico Not how I understood the question, but I can edit and add that variant as well.

Comment: i got the result at the bottom which was undesired as i said instead  of...(centered) i got .... (at the bottom), thank you for you help guys

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest that you load the `subcaption` package and use side-by-side `subtable` environments. The one on the left will contain sub-tables (a) and (b), and the one on the right will contain sub-table (c).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{subtable}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
text & text & text & text \\ \hline
text & text & text & text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL1}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL2}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
text & text\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{SUBTBL3}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Overall table caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```